# How does tension apply torque on a pulley?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, string

How is tension in a string able to apply torque on a pulley? How does string itself able to apply a force on pulley? What is happening inside the pulley?

The pulley has a mass $m$ and is a disc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's static friction, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Yes , it seems plausible , can you explain it using a diagram please ?

Comment: Hi @feynmanfan, welcome to Physics.SE! I'm not sure if I understand your question completely. Are you asking how a linear force like tension can become a torque?

Comment: No , the mechanism how string applies a force on pulley

Comment: That would be static friction between the string and the edge of the pulley.

Comment: Yep. If you squirt oil onto the pulley the string should start to slip (there could be a problem if the string absorbs the oil too readily).

Comment: I'm skeptical of the comments and answers so far.  My intuition is that pulleys only redirect the tension in a rope.  A wheel that significantly resists the pull would be a "belt", like a car's timing belt.  You would use a belt to turn a wheel which turns a gear.  A pulley would be a very bad choice for this.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of most ideal pulley problems, it's assumed that the string or rope doesn't slip along the surface of the pulley, so the pulley's edge moves along with the string. This could be called a static friction force, however, the value of that force doesn't come into account unless it's the specific focus of some problem. What matters in most contexts is that 1) it's tangential to the pulley, and 2) it's always big enough.

Since the edge of a pulley is essentially bound to the string along it, then any force that the pulley exerts on the string (and vise-versa) along the tangent of the pulley is parallel to the length of the string, so it interacts with the tension in the string. Of course, if the pulley has no external torque applied to it (and if it were massless), then it wouldn't do anything, and the tension in the string would be balanced by the tension in the string on the other side of the pulley.

[Torque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque) is a force applied about a fulcrum, either a fixed rotational center or a center of mass. Since the force from a string is tangent to the pulley, the torque is $\tau=rF\sin\frac{\pi}{2}=rF$.

Comment: Yes but why does the static friction equal the tension in the string .

Comment: @feynmanfan Static friction always equals the force it's opposing, by definition.

Comment: @ZettaSuro Ah ! Why is tension different then in both sides of the rope ?

Comment: @feynmanfan It's not different on both sides. Why do you think it is?

Comment: It can be different if the pulley exerts a force back on the rope, either by inertia or by an external force.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the pulley together with the segment of the string that touches it as a single object with
the same moment of inertia as that of the pulley, since the string is massless. As far as the angular
acceleration of this object is concerned, one is allowed to disregard the internal forces between
the aforesaid segment of the string and the pulley, and now T1 and T2 are actually external forces
responsible for the net external torque on the pulley-string segment system.See:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318107848_Force_and_torque_of_a_string_on_a_pulley

Answer (score 0):

Tasos' answer above is the simplest answer to the question.  With this approach you do not have to address the details of the interaction between the string and the pulley.  This is a great example of how picking the appropriate system (here the pulley with the string) leads to a simpler evaluation. This assumes no slip between the string and the surface of the pulley.